# AuthListener called multiple times

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Google's Firebase to implement login with facebook.

As per the firebase auth documentation, I register a listener.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
   _fbCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

   mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

   configureNoLoginButton();
   configureFbLoginButton();

   mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
       @Override
       public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
           FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
           if (user != null) {
              // User is signed in
               startMainActivity(mAuth.getCurrentUser());
           } else {
               // User is signed out
               Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User is signed out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           // ...
       }
   };
}
```

I put a breakpoint in the listener, and **it's called 3 times** with user != null.

According to the documentation, the listener might be called in these circumstances: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#the_user_lifecycle

Is it a good idea to start the main activity the first time the listener is called? (i.e. put a counter - if it's the first time, start the main activity; otherwise, do nothing).

Comment: Wheer did you set `mAuthListener`?

Comment: I register it in `onStart()` and unregister in `onStop()`.

Comment: Do it into onCretae and onDestroy

Comment: and make sure you call finish right after you start mainactivity.

Comment: Seems that this is a bug. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673616/firebase-android-onauthstatechanged-called-twice

Comment: This is know [issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/80)