# Firebase: onAuthStateChanged comes with old user Uid

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I get old (previously registered) user Uid in `onAuthStateChanged` after delete firebase account and then immediately creating a new one. But it is happen not every time, and I don't know what it is depends of. Any suggestions?

Also `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` is null into this callback, which is strange too.

Might deletion process depends of completion of `functions.auth.user().onDelete` in Firebase Functions, but I'm not sure.

```
@Override
public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

    // re-auth need for delete account flow
    if (reAuthFirebase){
        Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged reAuthFirebase");
        reAuthFirebase = false;
        return;
    }

    // ignore 1st callback http://stackoverflow.com/a/40436769/1621111
    if (isFirstAuthCallback){
        Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged subscribe 1st callback");
        isFirstAuthCallback = false;
        return;
    }

    String firebaseUserUid =  firebaseAuth.getUid(); // getting old Uid

}
```

Comment: How do you delete the account, from the console?

Comment: @AlexMamo deleting account from Android app

Comment: Are you deleting the account witout signing out, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm signing out before deletion

Comment: Tried to do not sign out before deletion of account and seems to this works

Comment: So it works only when you don't sign out?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, if do not sign out before deletion, the issue above does not happen, also does not happen issue with http error 400 while delete an account