# Why is Firebase Auth Signin and login segue being called twice

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Auth to sign into my app and then initiate a segue to the home screen. For some reason, when logging in the Segue appears to happen twice, whereas when the user is already logged in the segue happens once as intended. I am not sure where the issue is, here is the code for the login:

```
func login() {
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailInput.text!, password: passwordInput.text!) { (user, error) in
        if let user = user {
            print("User is signed in.")
            let verified = Auth.auth().currentUser?.isEmailVerified
            if verified == true {
                self.ref = Database.database().reference()

                CurrentUser.shared.getCurrentUserInfo()
                self.userName = CurrentUser.shared.username

                print("loginSegue")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToHome", sender: nil)
                print("loginSegue2")

            } else ...
```

On the console, the loginSegue prints show only once, whilst in-app it appears to happen twice like in this gif:

[image: Segue occurring twice]

I don't believe its an issue in the Home view controller as it does not happen when the user is already logged in and and the app initiates the segue from the initial view controller, here is the auto login code which seems to work fine:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        if let user = user {
            print("User is signed in.")
            let verified = Auth.auth().currentUser?.isEmailVerified
            let user_id = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            if verified == true {
                self.ref = Database.database().reference()

                let usersReference = self.ref.child("users").child(user_id!)

                usersReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    // Get user value
                    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    let name = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
                    self.userName = name
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "alreadyLoggedIn", sender: nil)

                })
            } else {

            }
        } else {
            print("User is signed out. (StartViewController)")
        }
    }
}
```

Why would that work correctly, but the login segue seems to occur twice?

Comment: This is just how the auth listener works in iOS (don't know about other platforms), it gets called twice. It annoyed me too. You can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673616/firebase-android-onauthstatechanged-called-twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this

```
Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
```

triggers when login auth happens and causes a segue from this part

```
usersReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
   // Get user value
   let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
   let name = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
   self.userName = name
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "alreadyLoggedIn", sender: nil) 
})
```

Comment: Thats the working example I used that works correctly, the part above (`func login()`)  is the one that does it twice not work, the part with `Auth.auth.signIn`

Comment: If `Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener` is in the very first `ViewController`, and the login function happens in a seperate `loginViewController` you're saying that the Initial viewControllers function is still called so I need to remove the stateDidChangeListener when segueing to the login View?

Comment: @PeterRuppert yes remove the state listener

Comment: @Sh_Khan Having a bit of trouble in figuring out how to remove the state listener are you able to provide an example?

Comment: @PeterRuppert completely remove `addStateDidChangeListener ` code and check current user if exists navigate to home if not to login

Comment: @Sh_Khan Instead I added `private var authListener: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?`, and edited the code to `authListener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener` and then removed it on segue to Login or Create account. `Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(authListener!)` so it will still login automatically and now will not be called after segue to Login view controller. Thanks!