# Is it OK/recommended to skip the second call from the firebase authStateChanges()-Stream?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

The firebase Authentication service offers a stream/event handler to get state changes on the auth status of the user (`onAuthStateChanged`), see

- [Authentication state @ Flutter Fire docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state)
- [Get the currently signed-in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)

According to the [Firebase Android API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener) + the question "[Firebase Android onAuthStateChanged called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673616/firebase-android-onauthstatechanged-called-twice)", this stream/event handler is called when:

> **onAuthStateChanged(FirebaseAuth auth)**
>
> This method gets invoked in the UI thread on changes in the authentication state:
>
> - Right after the listener has been registered
> - When a user is signed in
> - When the current user is signed out
> - When the current user changes

A quick test showed:

```
firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().listen((currentUser) async {
  if (prev != null) {
    print("object compare");
    print(prev == currentUser); // false
    print(identical(prev, currentUser)); // false
    print("============");
    print(prev.uid == currentUser.uid); // true
    print(prev.metadata.creationTime == currentUser.metadata.creationTime); // true
    print(prev.metadata.lastSignInTime ==
        currentUser.metadata.lastSignInTime); // true
    print(prev.runtimeType == currentUser.runtimeType); // true
    print(prev.hashCode == currentUser.hashCode); // false
    print(prev.displayName == currentUser.displayName); // true
  }

  if (prev == null) {
    prev = currentUser;
    print("prev set");
  }
}
```

Enough context. **My question**:

While setting up this stream, is it OK/recommended to

- process the first event
- skip the second event (e.g., with a $i counter)
- continue every other incoming event from the 3rd on?

**Why does this matter? What problem would it solve?**
This question is mainly raised for performance reasons.
When an event is fired (and a user is logged in), I execute actions like

- requesting a new/fresh token from firebase
- listening to the firebase realtime db to receive updates for this specific user

Skipping events that come directly after another and do not contain new data, can save us API operations and would be beneficial for performance/processing reasons.

PS: I do not consider the question "[Firebase Android onAuthStateChanged called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673616/firebase-android-onauthstatechanged-called-twice)" as a duplicate, because the answer from Fabricio is not marked as the correct one + from 2016 (things might have changed).

Comment: I'm unclear why you would want to skip anything at all.  I suggest editing the question to be more clear about what exactly isn't working the way you expect.  Please do not make us click through to other peoples descriptions of the problem - everything we need should be in the question itself.

Comment: I think skipping the first two calls (registration and login) is a good optimisation if it works for your program flow.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks. I edited the question and added a "Why does this matter? What problem would it solve?" section. - It is mainly about performance reasons and saving API/network calls. Everything that is related to the question is in the question. The links are just for further context if someone is curious. Let me know if there is something missing.