# How to overcome that the useEffect runs multiple times using React Native Firebase package?

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

Im trying to build a simple android app using [React Native Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage) for authentication listening to [onAuthStateChanged](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage#listening-to-authentication-state). If I understand correctly the onAuthStateChanged method have multiple states so it will trigger useEffect multiple times. The issue is that I want to trigger a function after authentication that checking if the user is inculded in a firebase-database, but due to this that function will get triggered multiple times and the will return undifined (twice) when I call it within the onAuthStateChanged function.

```
    const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState();
    const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);

     function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
        if (user !== null) {
          setUserDetails({
            name: user.displayName,
            email: user.email,
            photo: user.photoURL,
            theme: 'default',
          });
          if (initializing) setInitializing(false); 
          checkUserInDB()
        } else {
          setUserDetails(null);
          setInitializing(true);
        }
      }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);
```

To overcome this I can call checkUserInDb() function by leave it outside of onAuthStateChanged waiting for userDetails and initializing states to be fulfilled:

```
if (userDetails !== null && initializing === false) {
        checkUserInDb()
```

Although this will return the userDetails, if I log it it happens 3 times. I was trying to tackle it from a few angles (await /then/ timeout) but the issue is in useEffect and i just ran out of ideas. If you could point me to the right direction it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spent a few hours figuring out the issue and I successfully overcome it. I believe the `onAuthStateChanged` didn't like that I tried to set a custom state with the userDetails above. By using just user like in the documentation, I didn't have undefined returned. But it still not the solution to the problem as it will indeed onAuthStateChanged run 2-3 times before its settle. I found an other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673616/firebase-android-onauthstatechanged-called-twice/57338951#57338951) where someone used debouncing which I implemented and with a bit of refactoring my original logic it started working.

```
  var debounceTimeout;
  const DebounceDueTime = 200; // 200ms

  function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
    if (debounceTimeout) clearTimeout(debounceTimeout);
    debounceTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      debounceTimeout = null;
      handleAuthStateChanged(user);
    }, DebounceDueTime);
  }

  function handleAuthStateChanged(user) {
    setUser(user);
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
    if (user !== null) {
      console.log('=========> User is authenticated already:', user);
      checkUserInDb(user);
    } else {
      console.log('=========> User not found or signed out:', user);
    }
  }

useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);
```